# Python Logging - How do I disable a package's Logging?

Tags: python, logging, starlette, uvicorn

I am being driven mad by this issue. I want to just log using my basicConfig, but the module (uvicorn) is also logging to the file as well.

Example:

```
2019-11-27 14:44:29,595 - uvicorn - INFO - ('127.0.0.1', 62211) - "GET /consumption/xyz HTTP/1.1" 200

('127.0.0.1', 62211) - "GET /consumption/xyz HTTP/1.1" 200
```

I don't want the 2nd message to appear because it is a duplicate...how do I disable that?

Update:
Code used...

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.getLogger("snowflake.connector.network").disabled = True # remove snowflake network logging
logging.getLogger("snowflake.connector.connection").disabled = True
logging.getLogger('snowflake.connector').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.basicConfig(filename=f'{CFG.get("log_path")}',
                    filemode='w',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
                    )
rotating = RotatingFileHandler(f'{CFG.get("log_path")}', maxBytes=1024*1024*500, backupCount=4)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(rotating)
```

Log after setting access-log = False. I hit the API a few times:

```
2019-12-02 10:16:26,635 - uvicorn - WARNING - auto-reload only works when app is passed as an import string.
2019-12-02 10:16:26,656 - uvicorn - INFO - Started server process [20653]
2019-12-02 10:16:26,656 - uvicorn - INFO - Waiting for application startup.
2019-12-02 10:16:26,657 - uvicorn - INFO - Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-12-02 10:16:43,379 - uvicorn - INFO - Shutting down
2019-12-02 10:16:43,479 - uvicorn - INFO - Waiting for application shutdown.
2019-12-02 10:16:43,479 - uvicorn - INFO - Finished server process [20653]
Finished server process [20653]
```

Log when access_log = True:

```
2019-12-02 10:17:44,438 - uvicorn - WARNING - auto-reload only works when app is passed as an import string.
2019-12-02 10:17:44,459 - uvicorn - INFO - Started server process [20791]
2019-12-02 10:17:44,459 - uvicorn - INFO - Waiting for application startup.
2019-12-02 10:17:44,460 - uvicorn - INFO - Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-12-02 10:17:58,571 - uvicorn - INFO - ('127.0.0.1', 55861) - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
('127.0.0.1', 55861) - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Comment: have you read this ?  https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging the point --no-access-log

Comment: I am using uvicorn.run(), couldn't find the arg to pass in

Comment: This is a quote from the official web "If you're running using programmatically, using uvicorn.run(...), then use equivalent keyword arguments, eg. uvicorn.run("example:app", port=5000, reload=True, access_log=False)"

Comment: woops my bad, however, disabling that disables the message completely. I need just to remove the duplicate one.

Comment: Wait but first line is your custom log?..

Comment: Can you post the output after using `--no-access-log`.

Comment: Can you show how you configure your logging? uvicorn set's propagation to false on the access logger, so if they still end up in your logger there either is a bug or you are doing something that conflicts with that.

Comment: @ShagunSodhani - updated

Comment: @blues - yes, it is probably something to do with my configuration. I am just using basicConfig, but updated my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig` adds a `Handler`. Then you go and add another. Both directed to the same file.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=f'{CFG.get("log_path")}',
                    filemode='w',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
                    )
rotating = RotatingFileHandler(f'{CFG.get("log_path")}', maxBytes=1024*1024*500, backupCount=4)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(rotating)
```

So to see how to fix this it is best to look at what `logging.basicConfig` actually does:

```
def basicConfig(**kwargs):

    _acquireLock()
    try:
        if len(root.handlers) == 0:
            filename = kwargs.get("filename")
            if filename:
                mode = kwargs.get("filemode", 'a')
                hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
            else:
                stream = kwargs.get("stream")
                hdlr = StreamHandler(stream)
            fs = kwargs.get("format", BASIC_FORMAT)
            dfs = kwargs.get("datefmt", None)
            fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs)
            hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
            root.addHandler(hdlr)
            level = kwargs.get("level")
            if level is not None:
                root.setLevel(level)
    finally:
        _releaseLock()
```

Inlining `basicConfig` results in:

```
root = logging.getLogger('')
if len(root.handlers) == 0:
    filename = f'{CFG.get("log_path")}'
    mode = 'w'
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
    fs = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    dfs = None
    fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs)
    hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
    root.addHandler(hdlr)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

rotating = RotatingFileHandler(f'{CFG.get("log_path")}', maxBytes=1024*1024*500, backupCount=4)
root.addHandler(rotating)
```

Can you see the issue? The same file is setup with a `Handler` twice so to fix this write it as:

```
root = logging.getLogger('')
if len(root.handlers) == 0:
    filename = f'{CFG.get("log_path")}'
    hdlr = RotatingFileHandler(filename, maxBytes=1024*1024*500, backupCount=4)
    fs = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    fmt = Formatter(fs)
    hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
    root.addHandler(hdlr)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: you sir are a gentleman. Thank you for explaining the code in-depth. I understand now that the logger object I was using only needed one handler rather than multiple handlers. I was unaware of the handler added in basicConfig so thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Thank you :). I had thought I might have picked out an issue unrelated to the cause. It is sometimes useful to have multiple handlers as each can have their own format, level, and filters. But not when both are going to the same file.